Is it possible to use one line if-then in Python list comprehension?
I need to remove spaces from each element in this Python list:
x = ['abc', ' ', ' space ', 3]

I could do this:
v = []
for i in x:
    if type(i) == str:
        v.append(i.strip())
    else:
        v.append(i)

Which yields:
> v
['abc', '', 'space', 3]

I'd like to do it in one line. This works but only for strings. I need the "if" statement because you can't apply "strip" to the integer 3.
z = [y.strip() for y in x if type(y) == str]

I tried this but I get an error for invalid syntax:
z = [y.strip() for y in x if type(y) == str else y]

Is the if-else statement possible in one line?

[y.strip() if isinstance(y, str) else y for y in x]

if after for y in x is for filtering. You need to use if/else before for to create a ternary.
